# How to simulate browser login in Android using API

Tags: android, rest, http, cookies, authentication

I want to make an android app which will login to my web application using rest API. In browsers we have a concept of cookie which servers use to identify/maintain session with the users.

**In Android how would we accomplish it** ? I heard that there is a concept of token which is sent by server in response(first time when credentials are validated) and Android app have to send it to server every time it tries to access a resource(protected). So, what is the better way of doing it ?

**Do we need to validate the token again and again when the client requests for a resource ?**

Comment: Maybe go through [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/08/android-adding-sms-verification-like-whatsapp-part-2/) tutorial?

Comment: What is the problem with validating `the token again and again when the client requests for a resource`? I don't see any other way to authenticate an incoming request.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I can't think of a better way of doing this. Token based authentication seems to be pretty standard when dealing with RESTful APIs. Is there any reason you can't do that?

If you don't want to change the server code, then this could be simulated by adding a cookie header to every request you send. But this is basically the same thing that you mentioned above, just not as clean.

And the browser is already sending a token to be validated again and again. Every request has a cookie header that gets validated through your web application on every request, so this isn't a big deal at all.

And, you don't need anything Android specific to accomplish this. In whatever http library you're using I'm sure there is a method you can called or something you can override in order to set custom headers. Use that to set either your cookie header or token header on every request that you need to make.

Comment: Yes, but at the server end I need to check it again and again for every controller/action as opposed to using a security plugin such as spring security.

Comment: What technologies are you using on the server? You shouldn't have to explicitly do that for every request.

Comment: I am using grails,groovy on server side.

Comment: Then you would use something described here => (http://docs.grails.org/1.3.7/ref/Controllers/beforeInterceptor.html) to check for that token server side. There should be no need to code that token check into every request.

Comment: Yeah I am very well aware of interceptors but the problem is role checking. For every action in controller we have role annotation like ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER etc. to only allow authorized person to access it but using token it would be difficult and I have to manually check the role of user on every action.

Comment: So you're using this for role checking right now? https://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-role-generator   And your problem is that this role checking is already happening for you automatically, but it won't be if you use token-based auth like you were talking about? Am I understanding this correctly?